# Listen mic and return audio frame in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, webrtc, pyaudio

Is someone can explain me how to create a custom class audio which listen our pc microphone and return an audio frame ?

I made the same things for webcam here :

```
class CustomVideoTrack(VideoStreamTrack):
    """
    A video stream track that generates frames from a custom source.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    async def recv(self):
        pts, time_base = await self.next_timestamp()
        # Générer ou récupérer une frame vidéo ici
        # Exemple : créer une image noire
        ret, frame = self.camera.read()
        if not ret:
            print("Erreur de capture de la webcam.")
            return
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        # Convertir la frame NumPy en VideoFrame
        video_frame = VideoFrame.from_ndarray(frame, format="rgb24")
        video_frame.pts = pts
        video_frame.time_base = time_base

        return video_frame
```

Actually I need it for a aiortc project. I know mediaplayer exist but it's actually FULL of bug and I dont want to touch it anymore haha. If someone know how to do it for microphone i will appreciate a lot !

Comment: OpenCV has *undocumented* audio abilities. **do not** expect to use them for now.

Comment: do you have an idea which doesnt use OpenCV then ? Thanks for your answer !